# Connect to bluetooth device with Android/Java

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to make an android app that will connect to a device that I have that I suspect uses bluetooth frequencies. However, it seems that all the constructors in the `android.bluetooth` package are private. Does anyone have any experience they can share with me?

As a note, yes I've already looked at the API. I think I know what to use, but, again, I can't call any of the constructors of any of the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a close look at the BluetoothChat example provided?  This will show you how to scan for and connect to bluetooth devices as well as how to use the API to do so.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, I recently discovered the device uses a different frequency. Thanks, anyway!