# How to make the Bluetooth connection after device detected by swing application

Tags: java, bluetooth

I want to send the JSON data to mobile from window based java swing application. My app is able to search the device successfully but now i need to establish the connection with mobile and application. How can i establish the connection ?

```
public class BluetoothFinder {

public static final Vector<RemoteDevice> devicesDiscovered = new Vector<RemoteDevice>();
Object bluetoothName;

     public void BluetoothDeviceSearch() {
    final Object inquiryCompletedEvent = new Object();

    devicesDiscovered.clear();
    DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() {

        @Override
        public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
            System.out.println("Device " + btDevice.getBluetoothAddress() + " found");
            devicesDiscovered.addElement(btDevice);
            try {
                System.out.println("     name " + btDevice.getFriendlyName(false));
                bluetoothName = btDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
            } catch (IOException cantGetDeviceName) {
            }
        }
}

void printResult() {
    System.out.println("PrintResult method Taget Hit ..." + devicesDiscovered.size() + " device(s) found " + "New " + devicesDiscovered);
    System.out.println("Printing ...");

    Enumeration bluetoothDevicesList = devicesDiscovered.elements();
    while (bluetoothDevicesList.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object result = (Object) bluetoothDevicesList.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Bluetooth Device " + result);

        if (result.toString().equals("CC051B9C88DF")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bluetooth Device Name : '" + bluetoothName + "' Bluetooth Device No : '" + result + "'",
                    "Bluetooth Devices Search Result", 1);
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BluetoothFinder bluetoothFinder = new BluetoothFinder();
    bluetoothFinder.BluetoothDeviceSearch();
    bluetoothFinder.printResult();
    }
}
```

Above code is able to search the device but i don't how to establish the connection with window OS and android mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look:
[Connect to bluetooth device with Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751148/connect-to-bluetooth-device-with-android-java)
http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2010/01/08/connecting-to-bluetooth-devices-with-java/

Comment: I have gone through the URL but program is executing but hello word is not able to see on mobile device and i could not also get the response against sent request. I need to write listener. Can you guide me ?